# What is my Psychology degree worth in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

I've recently graduated with a masters in Clinical Psychology in Belgium. Is this diploma sufficient to be an accredited psychologist in the UK or would I need additional training?

Comment: I don't know exactly what the rules and requirements are but I think the most relevant accreditation would be the “[chartered psychologist](http://www.bps.org.uk/what-we-do/benefits-belonging/membership/chartered-member-cpsychol/chartered-psychologist/chartered-)” title from the British Psychological Society. Maybe their website will tell you what you need.

Comment: Anything labelled "chartered" is generally a much higher level than "able to work legally in that profession in the UK", which I think is what the OP is after.

Comment: You will need a NARIC as step 1 in any event.  http://www.ecctis.co.uk/naric/Individuals/Coming%20to%20the%20UK.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate regulatory body is [HCPC](http://www.hcpc-uk.org/).

The following titles [are protected](http://www.hcpc-uk.org/aboutregistration/protectedtitles/), meaning you cannot describe yourself as any of the following (professionally in the UK) unless you are on their register:

> • Practitioner psychologist
>   • Registered psychologist
>   • Clinical psychologist
>   • Counselling psychologist
>   • Educational psychologist
>   • Forensic psychologist
>   • Health psychologist
>   • Occupational psychologist
>   • Sport and exercise psychologist

Information on applying for registration can be found from HCPC [here](http://www.hcpc-uk.org/apply/). It is likely that you can apply under "International - EEA mutual recognition rights" - if your course is one that would allow you to practice as a registered psychologist in Belgium and you hold an appropriate citizenship (EEA member state or Swiss).